# Annotate custom camera video in android

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-canvas

i am using custom camera for capturing video in my application. I am able to record the video and saving it to directory. Now i want to add the feature of annotation  for captured video(Drawing with free hand in captured video and saving). I just implemented the free hand functionality, but i have no idea how to integrate with drawing with video. Is it possible in android ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.